# How to disable the browser's style sheet for disabled buttons?

Tags: jsp, cross-browser

In all the latest browser's the disabled buttons are acquiring the browser's stylesheets instead of the specified one. Is there a way to disable the browser's styles?
I am having JSP's to render the webpages with server code on Java , and doing a sanity on IE11, Chrome 33, Mozilla, Opera and Safari.

Comment: Even disabled button uses normal CSS assigned to them rather than using default browser's. You should make sure that you have properly assigned CSS class  to your button.

Comment: Well, yes, Application was working completely fine before the browser upgrade, so I believe there shouldn't be an issue with the way css is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure you are in need of this. The Web Developer add-on for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) and [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) is able to disable styling from the webpages

Once you have installed the plugin the option is available in the CSS menu. For example,

```
CSS > Disable Styles > Disable All Styles
```

**UPDATE**

You can unload a css by disabling it. Give an id to the `<link>` tag.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" id="style1" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" id="style2" />
```

And use this code:

```
 $("#A").click(function(){
 $("#style1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
 });
```

or

```
 $("#A").click(function(){
 $("link[href*=bb.css]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
 $("link[href*=cc.css]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
 $("link[href*=aa.css]").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

**Note:** While there is no disabled attribute in the HTML standard, there is a disabled attribute on the HTMLLinkElement DOM object.

Comment: Thank you, but I wish to know something that I can do from my application's end.As I would not be asking all the users of the application to reset their browser settings to run my application.

Comment: @Yasha. I have updated my answer. Please let me know Am i making sense? Thanks.

Comment: Let me try and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: the code block that you have suggested is to disable the css. Which style will it disable, the one that I have applied or the one that browser is applying? 
This piece of code did not work.